Question closed as "not focused" when it clearly has a unique interpretation parallel to sorting
This question: Sort the tuples from the cartesian product of an input 2-d array received several downvotes, and was then closed with the explanation with the reason: "This question needs to be more focused."
Judging from the definition here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions):

Needs more focus - If your question has many valid answers (but no way to determine which, if any, are correct), then it probably needs to be more focused to be successful in our format.
This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.


However, this clearly doesn't apply to the question at all. The problem is the exact same thing as sorting on a conceptual level. If there are multiple ways to interpret this question, then there are also multiple ways to interpret sorting.
The question also provides a very clear test case for further clarifying the problem.
Also, someone has already provided a good answer and they obviously didn't have trouble understanding the unique interpretation of it.
I'd like to see if more people want to answer and also leave my own answers in the future. Hence, I'd like the question re-opened.

Cataloguing the sequence of events (which I found funny)

The question was closed as "lacks focus". I was told this meant that it couldn't be answered. This was contradicted by the fact that it was already answered by that point.
The question was re-opened.
The question was closed again as "needs clarity".

I found it (subjectively) strange and amusing that the reason for closure changed in this manner.

"serial downvoted" you can't be serial downvoted on one question, unless you have reason to believe someone used more than one account to downvote that question (not very likely in this case) that statement is false.

Better not to get distracted by terminology. Yes, "serial downvoting" is the wrong term. Not what the OP wants to discuss (no matter if their stance is right or wrong).

Please carefully read the answer in the FAQ explaining the "Needs More Focus" closure reason. We can't realistically give you an entire algorithm for a custom task - even if it could be explained succinctly (and there's every reason here to believe that's impossible), it would not make something that could be helpful for others, because it's extremely improbable that they'd need the exact same algorithm in a different context, and even less likely that they could explain what they want in a single coherent query for a search engine.

There are many good questions on this site that pertain to a single algorithm. Also, almost every algorithm starts with some context that might or might not apply to other contexts in the future. Do we really want to be in the business of predicting the future? If this is a Q&A site, what is wrong with answering one question? As you can see, someone already did it just fine.

"The problem is the exact same thing as sorting on a conceptual level." - It's hard to imagine your basis for the claim. I guess you are saying that you want to do something like a topological sort on the output combinations (themselves a Cartesian product), except also somehow getting those values on the fly automatically in the correct order. That sounds like the kind of thing someone could write an entire academic paper about, not something that should be able to fit in a Stack Overflow answer. But aside from that, "multiple interpretations" has nothing to do with "needs more focus".

If people thought your question was ambiguous, that there were multiple ways to interpret the task, or that your test case failed to clarify the requirements, they would have chosen "Needs Details or Clarity" as a close reason, not "Needs More Focus".

If the question is too large for people to answer, they can just move on with their day. Why stop others (including myself) from posting an answer in the future?

Also: the answer that you consider "good" and that "didn't have trouble understanding" (again, nothing to do with "Needs More Focus") and that you accepted, does absolutely nothing to address your main objection to the approach you already figured out: "One way to do this is to generate all possible combinations with simple back-tracking and then sort them by absolute distance from the first array. But this will be very inefficient, memory wise." With that answer, you will still be generating and storing everything up front - only the sorting is on-demand via a priority queue.

"If the question is too large for people to answer, they can just move on with their day. Why stop others (including myself) from posting an answer in the future?" - because Stack Overflow is not a place for people to post answers simply because they are capable of answering. The question closure standards - all of them - exist for well considered reasons and have been refined over a 15+ year period. Please read: Why should I help close "bad" questions that I think are valid, instead of helping the OP with an answer?

I already implemented the answer they provided. It works fine and addresses my concern because I can terminate the program. It has one weakness - it is a heuristic and not strictly optimal. But it does address the memory concern I raised. You want me to share my implementation?

The problem here is you folks are presuming to understand my question better than me and others who have already answered it. The problem might be simply that the people voting to close it don't get it. And I regret I couldn't frame it well enough for them to understand. But at the same time, no question is "non-bad" enough that every person at every expertise level will understand it on a technical Q&A website.

Meta crowd, please do not vote to delete a question while it's being discussed.

Like I said, the presence of an answer (that was also implemented and accepted) refutes the very basis of tagging the question as "non-focused" and I'd like to see if more people answer as well as provide my own answers in the future. So please re-open the question.

@RohitPandey I'm not saying the question deserves to remain closed or otherwise, but that "an answer exists" is not "proof" of a question being adequately focused or even on topic. It's just proof that someone posted an answer. To speak about the question's fitness, just focus on the question itself.

It's not hard proof but an important data point. I strongly disagree that the question is so difficult that a reasonable algorithm can't be provided on this website. Since it is my question, the benefit of doubt on this should go to me. Like I said, I intend to post answers.

Not really, the user posting the question does not get "the benefit of the doubt". It's about the users who see the question, how they understand it, and how they interpret the site rules and guidelines. That's the way it works and the way it's supposed to work. That "you want to post an answer" does not make the question immediately on-topic.

This is on the question of "can a reasonable answer to this question be provided in the format of this website". I say yes it can. The benefit of doubt on that specific question should go to me, since I've obviously spent more time than anyone on it. I'm not an expert on the "constitutionality" of stuff.

"The benefit of doubt on that specific question should go to me". Again, not how it works. If you keep insisting on that, you'll get nowhere. Still, you already have 2 reopen votes (one of them presumably yours). So you only need one more and it'll get reopened. Focus on why you think the close reason does not apply, and you may get it reopened.

I intend to post answers is a promise we can't really take into consideration, though. A question is moderated on its current state. Not on a potential future state. And even then, the question is judged on its own merits. Not on whether or not it has answers.

Not a closure reason, but please consider that the question description is very hard to follow. The question repeatedly talks about "the n'th array" and only makes the distinction between input/output after the fact or implicitly. The rules for creating new arrays are also underspecified, as indicated by the comment asking about re-use (must the next array change one number, arbitrary many, ...?), plus it is unclear if "backtracking" is allowed (say the first and third element of input array 2 is used, can the second element then still be used?).

An algorithm question might not need code per se, but it does need the same information code would provide.  What do you have, what do you want, what have you tried, what is the specific problem you're running into.  You haven't specifically stated, for example, if you only intend to use Manhattan Distance (and you have comments implying that other metrics might be used) and are restricted to integers only.  Without a clear requirements list, the question is rightly flagged as "needs focus" - it's not really clear if you're asking a discrete math question or an analytic geometry question.

The answers below explain what exactly is unclear about your question. Please edit it and submit it for reopening, do not depend on comments to clarify your question. The question body itself without depending on the comments should be clear.

@DanielF - that's fair. I edited the question to clarify its a discrete Math question.

@AbdulAzizBarkat - I edited the question and addressed all the comments. I can't submit for re-opening since I already did that the last time it was closed.

A question having answers does not automatically mean it shouldn't be closed. (not commenting on your specific question since that isn't my area of expertise, just saying that isn't a valid argument on its own)

This is a small part of a larger problem. I have the algorithm for the larger problem implemented. I am the specialist on what I asked and weather it can be answered or not. Keep the hums to yourself.

@Clive - Looping through tuples in a cartesian product in a certain order is in fact very likely to be useful to other people in the future. The idea that "it's unlikely to be useful to a wide audience" is frankly ridiculous. Just Google cartesian product looping and you'll get all manner of hits like this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-construct-cartesian-product-tuple-list/
It has also shown up in my work multiple times.
Let's be honest, no one has done a wide review of the current and future state of algorithm problems in the world when they say it won't.

Also, has anyone done a review of weather this completely subjective, manual process that involves people pulling out their crystal balls and predicting the future actually help with quality? It's pretty clear it antagonizes and demoralizes and keeps new users and beginners away. It stunts the growth of the community. Is the improvement in quality worth all this? Has anyone quantified it? What if some day we find that all of this was for naught? Is it better than a coin toss? Is the emperor wearing long, flowing silk robes that are so light he doesn't even feel them? Or is he naked?

Please stop digging deeper into imaginary motivations of people and mechanisms as per your recent edits. The manual curation is the only one feasible, despite there being rules it is inherently subjective, and mistakes are made. It is perfectly fine to call out such mistakes or requesting clarification, but going too far and alleging ill intent or dishonesty is only going to muddy your case. Much of what was added to your post is just false and at some point people will just disengage instead of trying to unwind all misconceptions.

What part do you have an issue with?

I removed most of the motivation reading and stuck to objective retelling of what happened.

A charitable way to think about it is that the standards that are often imposed on beginners with questions are too high for beginners with questions.
I think that is reflected in the earlier answers here.
Personally, though, I think the community is rotting. People seem to close-vote or down-vote whatever they don't understand or don't know about, as if the opportunity to close-vote or down-vote is why they come to SO.
I started to see it with people harshly close-voting to protect their language tags.  That makes sense, but when there are other applicable tags, you should just make a tag edit.
Now the practice of being overly harsh has spread, and it's just the way we do things here.

I actually agree with the general complaint that many users dole out downvotes and close-votes on perfectly good questions too liberally. I don't agree whatsoever that this was an example, though. It's true that you managed to divine the asker's intent in this case, but with respect, that was a lucky guess. Your interpretation of the problem was flat-out incompatible with the example in the question, and you had no way of knowing that the example was simply wrong. (I assumed it was not and downvoted your answer accordingly; since learning the example was wrong, I've retracted the downvote.)

You could've improved the situation by editing the question to match your interpretation, by the way. That way your answer would not have appeared wrong to people like me who assumed the example was correct, and much of the ambiguity of the question would also have been eliminated. Though of course, that would've made things into even more of a mess if it had turned out that you were wrong about the asker's intent...

@MarkAmery - I agree with your assessment that the question in its original form was very poorly worded and had a mistake in the example that threw people off even more. However, I disagree that it was a lucky guess on Matt's part to interpret it correctly and answer it. The amount of luck required would be too large. A far more likely explanation is that he knew what to focus on and what to ignore (which he shouldn't have had to do).

Even after edits, this question remains deeply unclear. Let me record my thoughts and confusions as I read it from start to finish, so you can see what a reader unfamiliar with your problem experiences as they read your question...
First of all, note that upon reading the title, before looking at the body, I have basically no idea what the question is looking for:

An algorithm for all possible arrays in a order of distance from original

Even if we assume a reader can make a reasonable guess that the arrays contain integers and the definition of "distance" is taxicab distance (or its generalisation to >2 dimensions), there's simply no constraint on what kind of arrays can be output from this algorithm; is it meant to be an infinite generator emitting literally all arrays of integers whose number of elements matches some "original" array, ordered by taxicab distance from the original? Without reading the body, I have no idea what's going on.
It's not automatically closure-worthy if a question title doesn't even really hint at what's required, but it's a bad sign. It suggests either a difficulty expressing the question that is likely to continue into the question body, or that the question is going to be a dump of arbitrary requirements unlikely to ever be useful to anyone else (which will at least make it downvote-worthy).
But let's get into the body...

Give an array of arrays. I'd like to generate all arrays formed by picking the first element from the first array in the input, the second element in the second array and so on.

Huh? This sounds like, if a is your array of arrays, you want the array [a[0][0], a[1][1], a[2][2], ..., a[n][n]. (Obviously this implies a has size nxn.) But this defines a single array, and you're asking for "all arrays"; what's going on?
So I'm still confused. Let's keep going...

The order in which these arrays show up is important. The first array should be composed of the first elements of all the arrays in the input.

Wait, what? I guess that confirms I misunderstood the previous paragraph. But at least this first step of the problem is well-defined. Let's keep going...

The next array should be such that the sum of absolute distances from the first array should be the smallest possible.

Sorry, the sum of absolute distances from which first array? The first array in the input, or the first array in the output (i.e. the array of first elements we generated in the previous step)? If you mean we need to minimise the difference from the first array in the input, why can't we do that by making this second array in the output literally just be equal to the first array in the input? If you mean we need to minimise the difference from the first array in the output, then, I guess we just increase or decrease an arbitrary element in that array by 1 to get this second array? I'm not seeing any further constraints on what these arrays are allowed to contain, yet...

The third array generated should have the second smallest sum of absolute distances from the first one and so on.

Same confusions apply...

As an example, consider the input below.
[array([11,  9, 13,  7, 15,  6, 16,  4, 18,  2, 20,  0, 22]), 
 array([4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 1, 7, 0, 8]),
 array([ 9,  7, 11,  6, 12,  5, 13,  4, 14,  2, 16,  0, 18])]

The first array should be [11,4,9] (sum of absolute differences is 0). The second array should be [11,3,9] (sum of absolute differences is 1).

Aha! So that clarifies that the difference we're trying to minimise is difference from the first array in the output, not first array in the input. That's progress. And the example sort of hints that the arrays in the output have to consist of an element taken from the first array, then an element taken from the second array, then an element taken from the third array. After reading this bit, I finally understand that this is what the very first paragraph of the question was meant to convey, but it wasn't clear when I first read it because "the first element from the first array in the input" sounds to me like it means the first element of the first array.
Still I am a bit confused, though. The example seems (although it's not quite explicit) to be saying that [11, 3, 9] is the unique correct choice for the second array of the output. But why not [11, 5, 9]? That has exactly the same distance from the first array of the output (under any sensible distance metric), and 5 is also an element of the second array of the input, so presumably usable here?

The third array should be either of [9,4,9] or [11,4,7] (sum of absolute differences is 2) and so on.

Again, why not [11, 5, 9], whose sum of absolute differences is 1? Is this a mistake in the question? Or is there an implicit rule that the arrays in the output must be strictly in increasing order of distance from the first array - i.e. there can't be two arrays in the output with distance 1 from the first array?
Hmm... but you've said earlier you want all possible arrays formed by picking one element from each input array, so [11, 5, 9] has to appear in the output somewhere, doesn't it? Surely it therefore has to go here, then? I am again confused.

One way to do this is to generate all possible combinations with simple back-tracking and then sort them by absolute distance from the first array.

But again, that will include [11, 5, 9] as the second or third array in your output! So why weren't we including it in the example just now?

... [some performance stuff] ...
And the simple backtracking approach will explore arrays in the order where the first priority is to keep the first element 11 and the next priority is to keep the second element at 4 and so on.

Presumably it's implicit that when two arrays have the same distance from the first array in the output, they will be sorted in the order that they were explored? Okay, that partially defines a tiebreak rule for arrays with the same distance. But it doesn't concretely lay down why [11, 3, 9] was preferable to [11, 5, 9] earlier.

for calculating the sum of absolute differences of two arrays [a1, b1, c1] and [a2, b2, c2], we do this:
d = |a1-b1| + |a2-b2| + |a3-b3|.
So if the first array is [11,4,9] and the second one is [9,3,7] then the absolute difference is:
d = |11-9| + |4-3| + |9-7| = 5.

Cool, so taxicab distance rather than Euclidean distance. Good to have this clarified.

This is a small part of a real world problem involving splitting data centers in two groups for A/B testing. The details are too long, so will write a paper on it and share later. Rest assured, it is not a "school assignment".

I understand the instinct to add this kind of disclaimer to a question after people in the comments complaining that a question is homework, but it shouldn't really be there. A very succinct explanation of how you're going to use the algorithm in its larger context would be welcome (though unnecessary), but this doesn't even really explain that; it's just taking up screen space and making the question longer for no benefit to the reader.
(The comment complaining that the question is homework is obnoxious, by the way. It being homework wouldn't even be a problem if it were true! I would typically encourage flagging such comments for deletion, though in this case it's made a little trickier because there's also a suggested approach in the comment and that might deter the mods from wanting to delete it. You could still flag it with a custom flag reason, especially since the suggestion in the comment is nonsensical.)

Also, note that this question is very similar to sorting. Just as the interpretation of sorting is clearly defined, so is this question since its literally the same thing.

I don't really know what this is trying to say either.

In summary:

The title is vague and unclear, and as a consequence there's pretty much no way that this question will ever provide any value to future readers. How would anyone initially recognise that this question was even relevant enough to their needs to be worth reading, given the vague title?
Several bits of the problem spec are worded in ways that allow multiple interpretations, and only become disambiguated when you read further on and get to the example. This is needlessly difficult to understand even for a reader who spots the different possible interpretations on the first pass; a reader who doesn't may just write off the entire question as incoherent.
Even after carefully reading everything, there are crucial bits of the spec that don't make sense to me. In particular, why doesn't [11, 5, 9] appear anywhere in the result in your example? If I don't know what unstated rule prevents [11, 5, 9] from being included, I am confident that I don't understand your problem spec - and you don't give us any hints about what that unstated rule might be.
There is at least one outright contradiction in the spec: you say you want "all possible arrays" but then exclude [11, 5, 9].

Given the above, I think this question is unclear and deserves closure. In general I dislike the fact that staff removed our old "unclear what you're asking" close reason in favour of the new "needs details or clarity" reason, because the text of new one instructs the question asker not only to "clarify the problem" but also to add more content to their question (usually the opposite of what I want - frequently I want them to trim it down instead, remove contradictions, and then clarify the sentences that are already there), but in this case the new reason applies perfectly, since there is indeed a detail you need to add in order to make the question make sense: why doesn't [11, 5, 9] appear anywhere in the output in the example?
(Though even if you were to fix that, it's hard to care much about this question. It's a fairly arbitrary problem spec unlikely to be relevant to future readers, and even if it were, they're not going to find it due to the title - so how is this question ever going to help anyone other than you? This makes me, and probably other community members, uninclined to take a charitable view of the post when deciding whether close reasons apply to it, or to expend effort fixing the issues with the post or trying to get it reopened, even if it could be edited into a state where it's technically not deserving of closure under the rules.)

I'm reading through the whole thing, but let me address the point where "its fairly arbitrary and unlikely to be relevant and not searchable in the future" first. I have often been surprised by SO questions that pop up when I search for something on Google. Your making so many predictions about the future here. No one will ever run into a problem like this. Search engines will never be good enough to index and match to search queries, etc. The SEO of the question won't be improved. Like I said before, we shouldn't make these kinds of decisions based on our prediction of the future.

On the question being unclear, I added: "I'd like to generate all arrays formed by picking the first element from the first array in the input, the second element in the second array and so on. Obviously, there is a finite number of total possible such generated arrays. Each of those should show up exactly once.". [11,5,9] is indeed a valid output. But there are 131310 total outputs. It doesn't appear because I can't list all of them. Does this make the requirement of the question clear to you? Or still not?

@RohitPandey no, that first paragraph doesn't match what you want to do at all. You might as well remove it.

Actually, you're right that [11,5,9] should show up first since its distance is 1. That was a bug in the description. Let me fix it.

I think I addressed all the points now in the edits. The very last one in the first comment here.

@Mark I addressed all your points. Is the question still unclear?

@RohitPandey "No one will ever run into a problem like this" - you described a key factor when a question is not fit for Stack Overflow right there I'm afraid. Not in its written state, at least. The site has many rules, and the simplest thing those rules tell us is: only a subset of questions belong on Stack Overflow AND will do well.

@Gimby, the sentence you quote is Rohit's paraphrase of what I say in my post, and he's labelling it as a "prediction about the future" (and, implicitly, an unreliable one). I think you're interpreting his comment as him asserting that nobody else will encounter this problem, and him using this as a defence of his question - but that's not what he's saying. Quite the opposite!

I hadn't noticed there were so many points a distance of 2 away from the initial before your edit to the question. Impressive attention to detail.

I agree that the closure reason was wrong. The question does not satisfy the criteria for "needs more focus".

That said, I have to vehemently disagree that the question is clear.

The description about [element n] from [input/output] array is very hard to follow. The "picking the first element from the first array in the input, the second element in the second array" I already misread as [input[0][0], input[1][1], …]. The second paragraph would highly benefit by explicitly noting which "first array", "first one", "next array" and so on is input or output.
The entire specification for generating any array but the first is underspecified! As pointed out in comments it is unclear what the rules are for reusing/changing elements between steps - must one element change, can multiple elements change? In case of ambiguity (which even comes up in the example), is there a goal of reducing overall cost or not? Must the next element be adjacent to those already picked or can it be anywhere in the array? The example input elements are unique per array, but is this something an algorithm can actually rely on?


It's also under-specified as far as what distance metrics are intended to use (the example uses Manhattan Distance, but in comments it's implied the it may be extended to Euclidean distance) and whether inputs will necessarily be integer-only.  The simplest interpretation is a discrete math question that might be simple to explain in a concise answer.  The more liberal interpretation would be a doctorate paper in analytic geometry.

On the first bullet, I added a concrete example in that description to ensure that it is impossible to misinterpret.

@DanielF - I was just pointing out in the comments that I'm interested in one of the distance measures (of which there are other kinds). The question should be interpreted on the basis of the body alone. I don't measure any other distance measure in the body of the question.

@RohitPandey "On the first bullet, I added a concrete example in that description to ensure that it is impossible to misinterpret." Yet the text still has that confusing formulation. If there is text that is read one way and an example showing another way, that does not clarify things, that complicates things.

FWIW, I think what you actually want to do is: Sort the tuples of the cartesian product of the input arrays, where the sort key that is an arbitrary distance metric from each tuple to the first. Give or take a bit of jargon, that's literally it. That avoids a lot of ambiguity from the imperative description.

@MisterMiyagi - thanks! Updated the title of the question and the body. Didn't know that's what it was called.
